# While i'm trying to find common lists in a nested list, its values are changing?

Tags: python

Well, i need to find common lists between two nested lists and create a new one that contains these common ones and to label them with the letter `B`, the problem is one of the two nested list in changing!

I've tried to store it in another list `new_A`, even that one is changing !

```
A = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[0,1]]

B = [[1,4],[3,6],[7,8],[0,1]]

new_A=A

C=[]

for i in A:

  if(np.isin(i,B).all()):

    new_i=i

    i.append('B')

    C.append(new_i)


 print(C)

 print(new_A)

 print(A)
```

The output is this:

```
[[1,4,'B'],[3,6,'B'],[0,1,'B']]

[[1,4,'B'],[2,5],[3,6,'B'],[0,1,'B']]

[[1,4,'B'],[2,5],[3,6,'B'],[0,1,'B']]
```

Comment: `new_A` contains reference to `A`. I would recommend you to read the [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)(by Ned Batchelder) to understand the underlying concept.

Comment: try `new_A = [*A]`, maybe you need `new_i = [*i]` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need numpy or any temporary variables like new_i or new_A:

A simple code like this will work:

```
A = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[0,1]]
B = [[1,4],[3,6],[7,8],[0,1]]
C = list()  # same as C = []

for i in A:  # loop in A
    if i in B:  # check if B includes i
        C.append([*i, 'B'])  # append i with 'B' to list B
```

If you are looking for a "clever" one line code you can do this:

```
C = [[*i, 'B'] for i in A if i in B]
```

Or you can make use of set and intersection:

```
A = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[0,1]]
B = [[1,4],[3,6],[7,8],[0,1]]

# the inner list needs to be converted to tuple because list is not hashable
# we can create set of hashable elements only
set_A = set(tuple(i) for i in A)
set_B = set(tuple(i) for i in B)

# & is the intersection operator
C = list(set_A & set_B)  # [(0, 1), (1, 4), (3, 6)]
C = [[*i, 'B'] for i in C]  # [[0, 1, 'B'], [1, 4, 'B'], [3, 6, 'B']]
```

`*` and `**` are unpacking operators in python. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending in the same list that is the reason, check below code, use `i[::]`

```
for i in A:
  if(np.isin(i,B).all()):
    new_i=i[::]
    new_i.append('B')
    C.append(new_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_A` is a shallow copy of `A`. This means that they are both referencing the same underlying object. In your `for-each` loop you are iterating over the elements of `A` and modifying them as you go. This is why both `A` and `new_A` appear to change.

I am going to suggest a different way of doing this. It will depend on the order of the items in your list, but they can be sorted if that is not important. Try this:

```
A = set(tuple(i) for i in A)
B = set(tuple(i) for i in B)

C = A.intersection(B)        # {(0, 1), (1, 4), (3, 6)}
```